# Pre-Format the post editor for Wordpress

Tags: wordpress

I want to add some texts plus html code to every new wordpress post.

So, is there any solution to pre-define my texts and html code so that whenever i create new post and it already have the text and html code.

for example: I have html table for mobile prices and its one paragraph and i need this each time to add this in every new wordpress post.

So to save the time, Is there any option to add the html table and one paragraph so it automatically appear in every new post.

so that i don't need not have to retype them every time in new post.

Thanks and hope to see your reply soon.

Answer (score 1):

you can use [default_content](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/hooks/default_content/) filter to do that

```
add_filter('default_content', 'my_default_content', 10, 2);
function my_default_content($post_content, $post) {
    // Do nothing if this is not a blog post 
    if ($post->post_type !== 'post') 
        return $post_content;
    $content ='<h1>Any predefined content</h1>'
    return $content;
}
```

Comment: i add the above code in function.php file but after that when i create new post nothing i saw there specially "any predefined content in h1 tag. So why it is not working. I don't understand you mentioned above, that don't forget to update your_post_type witih proper post type name. what does it mean? do i need further customization after adding the above code in function.php file. Thanks and hope to see your reply soon.

Comment: @bradly looks like you want to add it to blog posts only, then your post type is 'post', I will update the snippet right now.

Comment: I can suggest you read this article since you are doing code customizations by yourself. https://developer.wordpress.org/themes/basics/post-types/